# How to get all contacts list after adding contact to my app contact store in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In order to get all contacts I use this code:

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
```

It works good, but when I add a new contact to my app contact store the FindContactsAsync method crashes and return "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception. In order to add app contact I use this code:

```
var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite,
                            ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly);

var contact = new StoredContact(store) { DisplayName = "Test Contact" };
var props = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
props.Add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, "1234567");
await contact.SaveAsync();
```

Comment: Where exactly (which line) causes the exception? Is there an InnerException, or a message of some kind?

Comment: @igrali var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync(); throw the exception with Message = "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: I received this exception, but it broke on a line with nothing wrong with it. I would suggest looking at (and probably posting) your constructor for 'StoredContact'.

Comment: I get in trouble with the same case. Have you found any solution ? it drives me crazy !

Answer (score 0):

You can't anonymously edit the `ContactStore` properties. By the default, you don't have enough permissions to do that. Take a look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469082/3503392)