# Adding contacts to People on Windows Phone 8.1 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to add contacts from my app to the People app on a Windows Phone 8.1? I looked at different things under the Contact class and nothing seems to work. There are different ways (like ContactManager, ContactPicket, etc.) to retrieve data but nothing seems to allow me to add a new contact as most of the stuff like SaveContactTask in Microsoft.Phone.Tasks is not implemented on WP 8.1.

J.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have write access to the primary contact store on Windows Phone 8, but you have the ability to create your [own contact store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactstore.aspx) for the app which you can use to manage contacts created in your own app.

The mechanism is pretty simple:

```
using Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation;

public async void addPerson() {
    var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();

    var contact = new StoredContact(store) {
        DisplayName = "Mike Peterson"
    };
    var props = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
    props.add(KnownContactProperties.Email, "mike@peterson.com");
    props.add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, "+1 212 555 1234");

    await contact.SaveAsync();
}
```

To inform the OS that you provide contact information, you need to add the `ID_CAP_CONTACTS`/Contacts capability to your app (in the Capabilities section of the appxmanifest). Contacts remain until the app is removed.

Private, owned by the app contacts are convenient for 'contact' data for the app.

Comment: Thank you.
Any idea how to get the contacts you create this way to be included in the People app by default please?
When testing on my phone I have to go in to settings -> applications -> people -> "filter contacts list" and tick the checkbox to includes my app's contacts.
I'm not fussed if this action by my app prompts the user to accept, just don't want them to have to navigate through the settings screens.

Wouldn't be so awkward if there was a URI for the people settings page. (I think they've added ms-settings:privacy-contacts in Windows 10)

Comment: I don't know of any programmatic way to get it included in the People app by default - nothing in the API makes it obvious as to how you would accomplish it.