# Windows phone 8.1 adding contact

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is any way to add contact to device contacts (People) on Windows Phone 8.1

This solution won't work for 8.1
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394013(v=vs.105).aspx

Do I need to revert to WP8.0, because regarding this post I can't
[Adding contacts to People on Windows Phone 8.1 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463192/adding-contacts-to-people-on-windows-phone-8-1-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the ID_CAP_CONTACTS/Contacts capability to your app (in the Capabilities section of the appxmanifest). Contacts remain until the app is removed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such API in order to add contacts to `People` as for the 8.1 version, yet. If you really wanted to do this, yes you have to revert back to the WP8.0. But still you could have a look at these for more:

- [Contacts API](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/11/14/windows-8-1-contacts-api.aspx)
- [Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.Aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to revert to Windows Phone 8.0.

You should be able to add your own contact store in your app.

Then when in the People app, you can choose to show contacts from your own app.

They will show up along side of the contacts from other installed apps.