# open the add new contact window in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have an add contact button which I want it to open the add new contact task of windows phone and return the added contact

[image: windows phone add new contact]

like android I already know I can add contact throw the following code from the question [Adding contacts to People on Windows Phone 8.1 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463192/adding-contacts-to-people-on-windows-phone-8-1-in-c-sharp)

```
using Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation;

public async void addPerson() {
    var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();

    var contact = new StoredContact(store) {
        DisplayName = "Mike Peterson"
    };

    var props = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
    props.add(KnownContactProperties.Email, "mike@peterson.com");
    props.add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, "+1 212 555 1234");

    await contact.SaveAsync();
}
```

Comment: You should use the `SaveContactTask` as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394013(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: is it available for windows phone 8.1 RT or winjs?

Comment: In Windows Phone certainly. In winjs I don't know.